# How to remove a Gridview from an ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-csv

I have an Aspx page that displays a GridView. The gridview would appear with data that was depending on which catergory was selected from a drop down menu. The user has the option to then download this as a CSV file (export to CSV).  I now want the Gridview not to appear (beacuse it is so large it often just hangs) but instead to be able to download a CSV file with the data from the gridview. I have successfully built the button allowing for the download of this data by clicking the button. However, I now cannot open the page without the gridView appearing. I tried to comment out the Gridview code - this just broke the page. I tried to set the gridview as Visible="False" but this did not work either. What else can I do to prevent the gridview from appearing and the user to be taken straight to a download dialogue box?

Comment: Can you post the code for page with your question?

Comment: please see above for the code used

Comment: @CodingNovice  Just use `display:none` for the gridview to  disappear but it will be available for in the `download` button

Comment: @Webruster Can you  use that command? I always thought if it was serverside it would need to be Visible="False" ?

Comment: yes, when you use `Visible=false` what actually it does is it removes the `HTML` where as `display=none` will not remove the `html` but can be see under the `Inspect element` so that you can access the gridview for the downloading

Comment: @Webruster I only have access the the asp.net code, can display=none be inserted into that or would this have to go into the CSS?

Comment: wrap your gridview to a `div` and set it to `display:none` in asp.net code

Comment: EX:   `<div  id="divhidegrid" runat="server" style="display:none;" >
  <asp:GridView ID="gvtest" runat="server" > </div>` like this

Comment: @Webruster Thank you this is very helpful

Comment: @CodingNovice I would appreciate if u can accept it as my answer so that it would be helpfull to someone

Comment: My answer would be appropriate one for your question as you are asking the way to hide gridview because you have written the code for download button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your `Gridview` to a `div` and set it to `display:none` in asp.net code –
Ex: `<div id="divhidegrid" runat="server" style="display:none;" > <asp:GridView ID="gvtest" runat="server" > </div>` like this

Comment: The answer you supplied to this question worked, the grid is now hidden. However, I have now decided that I don't want it to process the results in the hidden gridview as (although its not visible) it is still casuing the page to hang when the dataset in the gridview is of a large size. Is there anyway to comment the gridview out and just allow the user to use the "download to CSV" button?

Comment: Generally you are exproting the excel using the gridview, now in your case   then you need to change the appraoch of exproting to the excel. how may columns you are exproting? .. i troed with 32 columns around 10,000 rows  .. it never got stuck ..check with the Database Queries how data is retirieving

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. It is being retrieved via 1 call to the DB that queries the records in the table by ID an Name. The table has 12 columns and 15,000 rows. When displaying in the gridview it will hang after 2,000 rows. I want it to just allow the user to down the the CSV from the download button rather than populate the Gridview on the page (in the CMS) with all the records that it has retrieved.

Comment: sure will give a solution please start it as new Question, while adding question please include the existing button click event how you are exporting to excel. i will modify it and will provide a solution

Comment: I have created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051129/how-to-comment-out-a-gridview-and-return-dataset-in-a-downloadable-csv

Comment: @CodingNovice You may check my answer below, where you can export your data in required format without assigning it to the GridView. You may just select your criteria on the page and at the backend export your data query results directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data in DataSet or DataTable from Code Behind and then export it directly to Excel/CSV without assigning it to GridView such as in the following example to export it to Excel:

```
Public Sub ExportToExcel(dt As DataTable)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)
        Dim dgGrid As New DataGrid()
        dgGrid.DataSource = dt
        dgGrid.DataBind()
        'Get the HTML for the control.
        dgGrid.RenderControl(hw)
        'Write the HTML back to the browser.
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Data.xls")
        Me.EnableViewState = False
        Response.Write(tw.ToString())
        Response.[End]()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you get errors like **control must be placed in inside of form tag** you may also be required put the following code in your backend (Reference: [export-data-to-excel-from-datatable-gridview-aspnet-csharp](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/11/export-data-to-excel-from-datatable-gridview-aspnet-csharp.html))

```
Public Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
    ' Verifies that the control is rendered
End Sub
```

**C# Version of above code:**

```
public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
        dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dgGrid.DataBind();
        //Get the HTML for the control.
        dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
        //Write the HTML back to the browser.
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Data.xls");
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}

public void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    // Verifies that the control is rendered
}
```